Azure VM private IP is used for outbound access through Azure APIs instead of NAT Gateaway IP
so I have a VM (it has a NIC with a public IP for inbound traffic so I can SSH into it) within a subnet, that subnet has a Nat Gateway with a static public IP attached to it, and that static public IP is added to a firewall of some key vault (in a different subnet, different resource group). The thing is the outbound traffic to the public internet uses the correct Static IP address of the Gateway, however outbound traffic through Azure APIs uses the VM private IP. I can't post a screenshot since I'm new but I'll try to put the commands I executed from the VM and their response here:
curl https://ifconfig.me

Returns
172.X.X.X (the Ip address associated to the NAT Gateaway, so the expected outcome)

However
az keyvault secret list --id <keyvault-url> (And also curl to the key vault URL)

returns:
(Forbidden) Client address is not authorized and caller is not a trusted service.
Client address: 10.6.6.4 from unknown subnet
Caller: appid=ab79c54f-a98c-4ef2-9a52-e107d63f5300;oid=9a435f40-9754-4d49-89d2-
181cd98f60b2;iss=https://sts.windows.net/d04f4717-5a6e-4b98-b3f9-6918e0385f4c/;xms_mirid=/subscriptions/767b6496-1bf0-46d2-83c6-b83100f14269/resourcegroups/<rg-name>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/myVMSS;xms_az_rid=/subscriptions/767b6496-1bf0-46d2-83c6-b83100f14269/resourcegroups/<rg-name>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/myVMSS
Vault: <vault-name>;location=westeurope
Code: Forbidden
Message: Client address is not authorized and caller is not a trusted service.
Client address: 10.6.6.4 from unknown subnet
Caller: appid=ab79c54f-a98c-4ef2-9a52-e107d63f5300;oid=9a435f40-9754-4d49-89d2-181cd98f60b2;iss=https://sts.windows.net/d04f4717-5a6e-4b98-b3f9-6918e0385f4c/;xms_mirid=/subscriptions/767b6496-1bf0-46d2-83c6-b83100f14269/resourcegroups/<rg-name>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/myVMSS;xms_az_rid=/subscriptions/767b6496-1bf0-46d2-83c6-b83100f14269/resourcegroups/<rg-name>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/myVMSS
Vault: <vault-name>;location=westeurope
Inner error: {
    "code": "ForbiddenByFirewall"
}

Does anyone know what might be the cause or experienced this before ? Thank you in advance.
PS: I also tried to access the keyvault using curl and it's the same error.

This is due to having a service endpoint, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoints-overview
By disabling service endpoints on the Vnets, the problem gets solved.
